# Applescript to open application from CD Drive

Tags: macos, flash, applescript, cd, autorun

I have a flash program on CD which i need to auto run when Cd insert in drive.

```
tell application "Finder"
activate
if exists disk "MYRIAD" then
    tell application "Mac"
        activate
    end tell
end if
end tell
```

Meriad is my CD name and Mac is my flash application. it fire up the Mac application when i test it from desktop but when i burn it on CD it just open FINDER but nothing else.

Now i have also written code in my flash fla in second line to execute Mac application.

```
stop();
   fscommand ("exec", "Mac");
   fscommand("fullscreen", true);
   fscommand("allowscale", true);
   fscommand("showmenu", false);
```

i dont understand where i am going wrong.

please somebody help.... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways you can do this.

But try this.

```
 tell application "Finder"
    activate
    if exists disk "MYRIAD" then
            tell application "MYRIAD:Mac.app" to activate
    end if
end tell
```

Make sure you set the correct path in the   "*tell application "MYRIAD:Mac.app" to activate*"

line.

separate each directory with a colon "**:**" but do not put one at beginning or end  of the path to the app.

In my example the fist directory is the CD itself. The no other directories leading to the app.

Also make sure you name the app as it appears in the finder.

Comment: Hi buddy, your suggestion didnt work...anything else i can try? pls

Comment: Post the code you are using. It works my end no problem. Also explain in more detail "didn't work"

Comment: Ok, it gave me same result what i was getting previously with my code, it just opened FINDER but not open MAC.APP so it is not a auto run CD on mac.

Comment: i am just using applescript nothing else. my flash application is running fine. i just want to make a CD which will auto play Mac.app on  apple computer and PC.EXE on PC. thats it.

Comment: do you have any other idea to make autostart CD for mac? on windows i already made one with .inf file. Thanks again, i think i am bothering u with my own problem but really appreciate your help here.

Comment: It is not a bother but at this stage I will want to see the applescript code you are using. I will also like to know the full path to the app on the CD and what OS X you are using. without seeing what you are doing or knowing the bits or=f relevant info. I will struggle to help you. This is what think I understand. You have an app on a cd. You want to run a script when you run an applescript. The app name is Mac.app. I do not know what the app does but is a flash app.

Comment: right said, its a flash slideshow. i made a mac projector called Mac.app now its only root of CD. i also have applescript called MacAuto.app which is also in the root of CD. no folder in the root. now my applescript is as followed ---------------------------------tell application "Finder"
activate
if exists disk "MYRIAD" then
    tell application "Mac"
        activate
    end tell
end if
end tell

Comment: ???. But you have not followed what I said in my example?.  change your line  tell application "Mac"  to tell application "MYRIAD:Mac"

Comment: I tried that also but it gave me the same result as my own code. anything different other than this i can try?

Comment: can you select the app in finder the run this script and post the result.  tell application "Finder" to set thisFile to POSIX path of ((get selection) as alias)